# Tomcat's Spring app properties with docker container linking

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, linker, docker

I have been playing a bit with docker.

I have my mysql container

**docker run --name mymysql -d mysql/mysql-server:5.6**

my tomcat container where my app is deployed

**docker run --link mymysql:mysql -d my tomcat**

in the tomcat container I can see (because of the linking)

```
..
MYTOMCAT_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.55
..

and in the /etc/hosts
172.17.0.55 mysql
```

in my spring application I manage properties this way

```
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:${env}/myapp.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

where depending on the configuration (prop variable is set -Denv=qa in the JAVA_OPTS of tomcat)

in the qa/myapp.properties I have for example the mysql link

```
databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/mydb
```

where the 'mysql' is the name of the mysql docker image and the same as in the /etc/hosts of the tomcat container

I was wondering if the way I'm handling thing is considered good practices ?
Is there an easier/cleverer way of handling the properties ? The fact that my java app is strongly linked to the name of my docker's image bother me a bit.

I was thinking having a kind of scripts that run on the tomcat container that builds the final may.properties using the ENV variable (MYTOMCAT_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR) instant of using /etc/hosts values. Is this something which would be a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tackled this myself. In order to not tightly couple your mysql database container to your could use another JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS to pass your mysql url which is then used in your databaseUrl. So for your example, you could do this:

```
docker run --link mysql_container:mysql -e JAVA_OPTS="-Denv=qa -Dmysql_url=//mysql:3306"
```

And then in your configuration for the connection:

```
databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql:${mysql_url}/mydb
```

Let me know if any of that doesn't make sense. Many of the examples I found were just slightly not giving me the full answer so I can understand if you need more info.